# Use java to modify file contents in place

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream, nio

I need to modify specific contents of a file **in-place**.
I do **not** want to create a new file and rewrite the old. Also the files are small just a couple MB each the max.
For those wondering (although I am not sure if this is related to the OP), I need to modify files that are part of version control and need to modify a read-only version. It is much simpler to do the modification in place.
Is this possible with Java apis?
If not is there a library that offers this?

Comment: Why do you not want to create a new file to replace the old one? That's much more robust in the presence of failure, since you haven't partially overwritten the original file if it fails in the middle.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html

Comment: What level of API are you looking for? Are you OK working with raw bytes, or do you want to be able to manipulate it as text, insert/delete/modify strings, etc?

Comment: You're better off writing a new file from the old file, deleting the old file, and renaming the new file.  If you try to add more information to the middle of a file, you'll corrupt the file contents.  Better yet would be to delete the .old file and rename the old file with a .old extension.  That way, you don't lose the file if your I/O is interrupted.

Comment: _" I need to modify files that are part of version control and need to modify a read-only version"_ -- Read-only means the file cannot be written to (or deleted), whether or not you are doing it in-place.

Comment: @JimGarrison:Interesting comment.I need to replace with smaller number of bytes

Comment: @JimGarrison:My bad.The file will be modifiable.

Comment: @JimGarrison:`You cannot insert bytes in the middle of a file without rewriting everything after the insertion point.`.So you are saying in that case the rest must be shifted?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc:No, it is not that simple.The new file will not be under source control.I will have to find a way to add it.I am trying to avoid this

Comment: Which source control system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java allows random access and writing to files on disk.  However, writing to the middle of a file can only over-write bytes -- i.e. replace specific bytes with other bytes -- and cannot *insert* data into the middle of a file.  To do that you must rewrite everything after the insertion point.  Think of the file as an array of characters (`char[]`) that happens to reside on a disk.  Random-access allows you to do the equivalent of

```
char[] file    = ... // the file on disk
char[] newData = ... // the data to be written
int pos = ...        // the position in the file to write to
for (i=0; i<newData.; i++) 
{ 
    file[pos+i] = newData[i];
}
```

To *insert* data in a file would require the same process as inserting data into an array. All data after the point of insertion would have to be moved to the right to accommodate the inserted data.  If you are replacing with a *shorter* string (i.e. removing bytes) then the data after the edit would have to be shifted left.

Secondly, you state:

> I need to modify files that are part of version control and need to modify a read-only version

Read-only means exactly that.  If the file is read-only, you cannot modify it in any way, whether you use random access or not.

You also said in a comment:

> The new file will not be under source control.I will have to find a way to add it.I am trying to avoid this

If the file is under source control, you are most likely working on a *local copy*.  As long as the updated file has the same name as the original and is in the same directory, it should make no difference if you create a new instance of the file.  You merely have to commit the updated version to the source control system.

If, however, you are updating the file *within the source control system's repository* then you are likely to permanently damage the system.

Comment: In my case i actually have to replace **less bytes** than the existing.For example: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO` with `ABC`. Wouldn't this work?

Comment: You are right.The working copy will be local.But I am not sure about if I use the same name it would make no difference.I mean I would have to delete the file and then create a new version with the same name.Once I delete the file why would the new file be considered under source control even with the same name?

Comment: NO.  Look at my edits above.  If you replace with fewer bytes, you must shift later data left (and shorten the file).  But all of this is unimportant.  If you are working on a local copy, just make a new file and re-commit.  If you are trying to change the source control repository files directly without the source control system's knowledge, you are on your own and likely to cause major damage.  Source repository files are not intended to be touched except by the source control software.

Comment: The source control system cares only about the file name and data contents, not the file's physical location on disk.  If you locally delete a file in your working copy, then recreate it with the same contents, _wihout notifying the source control system_, the source system should treat it as unmodified.

Comment: 1)What if I just add space char to all extraneous data and not shift anything left?2)What is the difference when I manually change a file?The system just knows that it is checked-out.**I** am modifying it.Not the system

Comment: I suggest you do the following experiment: (1) Create a small file called `a.txt` and check it in. (2) Make a copy of the file called `b.txt` (3) Delete `a.txt` (4) Rename `b.txt` to `a.txt` (5) Ask Clearcase for the status of files.  It should say `a.txt` is unmodified.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19180/discussion-between-jim-garrison-and-cratylus)

Comment: Apparently while I was reading on my phone I accidently down voted this. I will fix it as soon as it unlocks me from voting again. I take that back it appears I am locked in. Jim, could you make a minor edit to the text so I can fix the down vote.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell:I think this will not work.Perhaps is a bug in a SO.I never managed to upvote a second time after an answer has been edited

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to be able to manipulate the file content as text, and assuming that the file fits in memory (which you say is a valid assumption), then perhaps you might find the methods in Commons IO `FileUtils` useful:

http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

For example:

```
File f = new File("my-file.txt");
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(f, "UTF-8");
List<String> outLines = modify(lines); // Do some line-by-line text processing
FileUtils.writeLines(f, "UTF-8", outLines);
```

So, you're reading the file content into memory, modifying it in-memory, and then over-writing the original file with the new content from memory. Does that meet your criteria for "in-place"?

Comment: In place means not create a new file and overwrite the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Java supports random file access, in particular using `seek()`.

Have a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html

Comment: *Random access files permit nonsequential, or random, access to a file's contents. To access a file randomly, you open the file, seek a particular location, and read from or write to that file.*