# In Java, can I remove specific bytes from a file?

Tags: java

So far I managed to do something with Byte Stream : read the original file, and write in a new file while omitting the desired bytes (and then finish by deleting/renaming the files so that there's only one left).

I'd like to know if there's a way to directly modify the bytes without requiring to manipulate more than one file. The reason is because this has to be performed when there is low memory and the file is too big, so cloning the file before trimming it may not be the best option.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258714/use-java-to-modify-file-contents-in-place

Comment: When memory is low, what you do is read a small buffer each time and write it immediately, until you reach the data you need to modify, modify it, write it, and keep on going with small buffers. You don't read the entire file to memory. If you are low on disk space, that's another issue.

Comment: According to this: https://www.cs.ait.ac.th/~on/O/oreilly/perl/cookbook/ch07_11.htm , you have to use more than one file, or read the entire file into memory, because of the way Operating Systems treat files.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to know if there's a way to directly modify the bytes without requiring to manipulate more than one file.

There isn't a SAFE way to do it.

The unsafe way to do it involves (for example) mapping the file using a `MappedByteBuffer`, and shuffling the bytes around.

But the problem is that if something goes wrong while you are doing this, you are liable to end up with a corrupted file.

Therefore, if the user asks to perform this operation when the device's memory is too full to hold a second copy of the file, the best thing is to tell the user to "delete some files first".

> The reason is because this has to be performed when there is low memory and the file is too big, so cloning the file before trimming it may not be the best option.

If you are primarily worried about "memory" on the storage device, see above.

If you are worried about RAM, then @RealSkeptic's observation is correct.  You shouldn't need to hold the entire file in RAM at the same time.  You can read, modify, write it a buffer at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove bytes in the middle of the file without placing the rest of the file in memory. But you can replace bytes if it can help you.