# Json edit object using Jackson(Java)

Tags: java, json, jackson

New with Jackson here.
I have the Person class, and list of persons in json format, listed in Arraylist.
Person class contains this:

```
int id;

@JsonProperty("Lastname")
String lastName;

@JsonProperty("Firstname")
String firstName;

@JsonProperty("BirthDay")
String birthDay;

@JsonProperty("Emails")
ArrayList<String> emails;

@JsonProperty("Languages")
ArrayList<String> languages;

public Person() {
}

public Person(int id, String lastName, String firstName, String birthDay, ArrayList<String> emails, ArrayList<String> languages) {
    this.id = id;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.birthDay = birthDay;
    this.emails = emails;
    this.languages = languages;
}
```

Plus getters, setters and toString.

I'm reading all objects from json file, and adding it to ArrayList

```
static ArrayList<Person> personArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The search:

```
public static List<Person> searchByID(int id) {
    List<Person> search = new ArrayList();     
    for(Person person:personArrayList)
    {
        if(person.getId()== id)
        {
            search.add(person);
        }
    }      
    return search;
    }
```

The question is: when I find an object to array list, how can I edit it? I need to change some fields and write an object to json file, but not as new one, just edited old one. How can I do this?

Comment: can you elaborate your question ?

Answer (score 0):

So your question is about how to write json data optimized in a file. 
Have a look at this question's answer, it explains how writing to files works in Java and that your idea is not working with Java's random access to files:
[Use java to modify file contents in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258714/use-java-to-modify-file-contents-in-place)